# Is this LINQ expression enumeration unsafe because it modifies one of the objects in the expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my code, I have three lists.

1. A list of items I've queued for creation/retrieval (requested)
2. A list of items that I'm currently building (working)
3. A list of items I'm missing from the last request. This may include duplicates of items I've already requested and working on retrieving. (missing)

I only want to queue up requests for items that I have not already queued requests for or are working on, the following LINQ expression crossed my mind...

```
// Queue object requests if they aren't already requested
foreach (int id in missing.Except(requested.Concat(working)))
    requested.Enqueue(id);
```

However, red flags went off here assuming that Except is using deferred execution, that I may be modifying the list while enumerating it, which would normally throw an exception or cause problems.

Sure, I can rewrite this without using LINQ and/or check each list separately and then add to it afterwards, but the question remains. Why or why doesn't this work? I thought it would probably throw an exception, so I wrote the following test:

```
private void Test()
    {
        Queue<int> missing   = new Queue<int>();
        Queue<int> requested = new Queue<int>();
        Queue<int> working   = new Queue<int>();

        missing.Enqueue(5);  // also in working
        missing.Enqueue(10);
        missing.Enqueue(67);
        missing.Enqueue(96); // also in requested

        requested.Enqueue(47);
        requested.Enqueue(66);
        requested.Enqueue(84);
        requested.Enqueue(89);
        requested.Enqueue(96);

        working.Enqueue(1);
        working.Enqueue(5);
        working.Enqueue(33);

        foreach (int i in missing.Except(requested.Concat(working)))
            requested.Enqueue(i);
    }
```

This code works and returns the expected result (requested now contains 7 items including 10 and 67). I thought that might throw an exception.. So, was I wrong and this is just fine or am I right that this would cause problems?

(obviously the question isn't how to make it work, because I know I can just check requested first, but I wanted to understand the workings of this LINQ expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the potential O(n^2) of comparing all elements of one set to another Except internally uses a hash set to partition the collection items via their hash codes and then only compares the items in each bucket.

The result of this is that Except isn't actually a lazy LINQ operator and is evaluated completely as you read off the first item.

Comment: This is true for `Enumerable.Except<T>` but `Queryable.Except<T>` is a different beast.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The other answerer deleted his answer, but I thought it was also valueable. (Call .ToList() to ensure it is fully evaluated). But, your answer does explain the behavior.